# Muscle groups for different exercises

Tags: muscle, pull-ups, chin-ups

I would like to know which muscle groups the following exercises train:

- Regular pull ups
- Wide grip pull ups
- Close grip pull ups
- Close grip chin ups

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that a little bit of research could have answered.

Comment: [ExRx](http://exrx.net/Lists/ExList/BackWt.html#anchor125439) is a good place to look up specific muscle groups for each exercise.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are exercises focused in back as a primary muscle and also work biceps as a secondary muscle and of course your grip strenght. By experience I would do the regular pull ups and the regular chin ups those kind of grips you mentioned do the same work as the regular grip so keep it simple.